Particle system motion blur with dinamic geometry
Recently I found a very anoyinng problem with the motion blur and the simulation zone. Basically if you create a particle system, you asign an age to the particles, and you try to render when the particles are starting to be deleted, you'll find that the motion blur is totally broken. This is a well known problem and you can try to fix assigning manually the IDs (for example with random numbers).
I was testing a different method to achieve the same result (my project is an object that disolves, and emits particles and smoke while it's disolving) so I wanted to test the particle system integrated in blender, just to compare with the simulation zone. And I found that the particle system in Blender have exactly the same problem with the IDs. Apparently it have something to do with the geometry pipeline in Blender, but if, for example, you create an object and the geometry of the object is changing (for example if some faces are deleted during the animation) when you try to emit particles from this object, you'll have corrupted motion blur. AND in simulation zones you can manually add an ID, but in the particle system you don't have any opportunity to solve this since you can't asign an ID manually, so the only option that you have is to switch off the particle system.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?
Attached you can see a failed motion blur vs a correct one


Blend File example:

